# Graph matching - normalize similarity matrix and decrease/increase uninformative/informative matches

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, normed-spaces

I'm working with some graph matching algorithms that output a similarity matrix between nodes from different graphs and that I wish to match as best as possible.
Unfortunately, some nodes might be too uninformative and match well with a lot of nodes and that will affect the matching of nodes that are informative and might have just one strong match.
I've read that applying the *Sinkhorn Knopp* would normalize and make row sums equal to 1 and columns sums equal to 1 too and in the process decrease the influence of uninformative nodes and increase the effect of informative ones.

As I'm quite unfamiliar with Mathematics and can't find any good explanation, I'm asking why would this transformation have the effect I want?

Also, I'll rarely have a square matrix so I think that bistochastic normalization is out of the way? I've use l2-norm and the rows and cols sums are relatively balanced and all close to 1. Will l2-norm suffice for what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide more details? Also, why standard matching algorithms do not work?

Comment: I've been using _Blondel_ and _Heymans_ algorithms to generate the similarity matrixes between nodes. I want to match the nodes of both graphs and I know that the matching should be one-to-one. The graphs don't represent the same thing but I know they have a connection/matching for sure. But even having a connection, the structure can be different and that is why the matching isn't straightforward or relatively easy. Also, the graphs have different labels and that is why I must match them this way. In tests I know the matching and want to evaluate the matching method.

Comment: Also, I've started with these matching algorithms for nodes but I don't know and haven't used other matching algorithms. Can you tell me what you refer to as standard matching algorithms and some references to get some insight? Would appreciate that a lot!

Comment: I was wondering if you could get any usable result from mapping similarities in some way into edge weights of a weighted bipartite graph on $V(G_1) \cup V(G_2)$ and calculating maximum weighted matching (there's [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), but an LP solver could give you more flexibility if necessary).